# Getting Django working with https using nginx gunicorn and unix sockets

Tags: django, nginx, https, gunicorn, unix-socket

I've been trying to get my Django site setup with https using Let's Encrypt. I've been running this site without https for a little while so I know the basic configuration works without https but after setting up the https stuff I get a "Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server" error. Here is my nginx configuration file:

```
server {
#listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;
server_name servernameredacted.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/servernameredacted.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/servernameredacted.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

location /static {
    alias /home/ubuntu/sites/servernameredacted.com/static;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/servernameredacted.com.socket;
}
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name servernameredacted.com;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

and here is my gunicorn upstart file:

```
description "Gunicorn server for servernameredacted.com"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid ubuntu
chdir /home/ubuntu/sites/servernameredacted.com/source/servernameredacted

exec ../../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
        --bind unix:/tmp/servernameredacted.com.socket \
        servernameredacted.wsgi:application
```

If you can help me out I will write out the process for this in a tutorial for the rest of the web.

Comment: Please post your nginx and gunicorn error logs.

Comment: Do the `/static` files work?

Comment: There is a missing ' in the ssl_ciphers line

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that I wasn't paying attention to the sites purpose and I was trying to access the root of the domain rather than the /admin area. This site had no root web pages, just an admin area so when I tried the admin area the whole thing just worked, as it should.

**I used these web pages to figure this out:**

[Digital Ocean on Nginx and Let's Encrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04)

[Youtube video on: SSL for HTTPS with nginx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0L3u2Vn3Wo)

**Other useful references:**

[Readthedocs for Gunicorn](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.io/en/19.3/index.html)

[Readthedocs for Letsencrypt](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)

I'll leave this here to help others in the future...